# Non-Big-O Notation: What is the time complexity of 2 comparison operations joined by "and"?

Tags: python, big-o

I'm currently doing a class assignment and would like to ask a quick question about time complexity whenever we have 2 comparison operators joined by the word "and". Would it be O(1) or O(2) in Non-Big-O notation? Because I want to trace every operation in my own algorithm.
For instance, What would be the time complexity of line A in Non-Big-O notation would it be O(2)?

```
list1 = []
counter = 0
If len(list1) > 0 and counter!= max:  #line A
  list1.append(counter)
  counter += 1

return list1
```

Comment: "O(2)" isn't a thing so I don't really know what you're talking about with that, but in general terms, if you want to see how long an operation takes you can time it.

Comment: Yup I understand Big-O where its mostly O(1) if we have a constant operation. But as I need to trace every operation in this assignment, I'm wondering if the code len(list1) > 0 and counter!= max actually performs exactly 2 computations instead of 1.

Comment: What is "non-big-O" notation? This Stack Overflow question is the only relevant thing that shows up on Google when searching for it.

Comment: I meant it as the exact number of computations

Comment: Time it and find out.

Comment: Alright, point noted. Thank you!